# Trouble running Android serial monitor lite on HCL ME U1

Tags: android, usb, tablet, host, ftdi

I am trying to run this [USB Serial Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ksksue.app.terminal&hl=en) app on HCL ME U1 tablet (ICS 4.0.3, Kernel 3.0.8). I am connecting the tablet with a serial device using a FTDI FT232RL (USB to RS232) cable. When i connect the FTDI cable to tablet, notification asking permission to connect the device pops up and when I open device, Toast saying connected also comes up. But when i write some data, the data is not send. The TX Led doesn't blink. So the data doesn't get past FT232 IC.

I have tried same app on android x86 using oracle VirtualBox. It works fine on it. No errors.

I have tried Slick USB 2 Serial terminal on both x86 & ME u1. It works on both.

Please share if anybody has any ideas what the problem might be.

[Source code](https://github.com/ksksue/Android-USB-Serial-Monitor-Lite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Question have become obsolete. FTDI and prolific have released their driver jars for android. They are working fine.

Comment: Actually they're not, I'm having troubles with the Prolific driver :)